# How to search @ | & ( ) in sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

How to search @ | & ( ) in sphinx.

I want the results contains these symbols,  it is keyword for sphinx,  how should I search these stuff?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape those characters by inserting a '\' before it, or use Riddle.escape(string). Here is an related issue one github: https://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx/issues/235

Answer (score 0):

To be able to search by this characters you need to add them into charset_table, see [charset_table documentation](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table)

And of course you need to escape them in search query, like:

```
$sphinx->Query($sphinx->EscapeString("my@email.com"));
```